New RSA key not able to validate jwt
I have some scripts to generate a private key using the open-ssh
Like so:
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048


openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -out "public_key.pem"

After that, I am using the private key to encode a jwt and the public key to decode/verify it in a nodejs(Nestjs to be more precise) application.
The problem is that after I generate new ones using a script, the public keys are not able to verify the jwt. Same infra, same code, same everything, but no verifying.
Here is the guard that I am using:

@Injectable()
export class SessionGuard implements CanActivate {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(SessionGuard.name);

  constructor(
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
    private readonly jwt: JwtService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const req: FastifyRequest = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    try {
      this.jwt.verify(req.authorization.access_token);
      Object.assign(req, { auth: { access_token: auth.access_token } });
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      ...
    }
  }
}


Even after investigation and reducing the variables to a singular constant, like checking different commits, different branches and so on and so forth, I ended up just grabbing an older private and public key pair. And they worked. So I concluded that the private or the public keys are the problem. So I started looking at the differences between them.
The public keys are identical:
New public key:
  File: Babylon/babylon-vault/new_public_key.pem


  Size: 451         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,1   Inode: 55875137    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   andre)   Gid: ( 1000/   andre)
Access: 2024-10-10 09:50:48.267558013 +0300
Modify: 2024-10-10 10:09:21.210201256 +0300
Change: 2024-10-10 10:09:21.210201256 +0300
 Birth: 2024-10-10 09:46:06.462084565 +0300


Old public key:
  File: ../Babylon/babylon-dashboard/old_public_key.pem
  Size: 451         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,1   Inode: 58335596    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   andre)   Gid: ( 1000/   andre)
Access: 2024-10-10 09:09:44.430166085 +0300
Modify: 2024-10-09 23:23:44.486503583 +0300
Change: 2024-10-10 09:43:02.288654750 +0300
 Birth: 2024-10-10 00:18:19.577690685 +0300

But the private keys differ by only one aspect, even tho they are generated by the same script:
New private key:
  File: Babylon/babylon-vault/new_private_key.pem
  Size: 1704        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,1   Inode: 55836734    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/   andre)   Gid: ( 1000/   andre)
Access: 2024-10-10 10:10:56.585222597 +0300
Modify: 2024-10-10 10:08:05.675344123 +0300
Change: 2024-10-10 10:08:05.675344123 +0300
 Birth: 2024-10-10 09:46:06.420084468 +0300

Old private key
  File: ../Babylon/babylon-vault/old_private_key.pem
  Size: 1700        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,1   Inode: 58335543    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/   andre)   Gid: ( 1000/   andre)
Access: 2024-10-10 09:09:44.564168027 +0300
Modify: 2024-10-09 23:24:53.945618329 +0300
Change: 2024-10-10 09:43:00.327654796 +0300
 Birth: 2024-10-10 00:18:19.513689691 +0300

As you can see, the size differens from 1700 on the old one to 1704 to the new one.
I have no idea why. This is valid on all platforms(Windows, Mac, Linux) and in the debugging process I arrived at the native crypto.validate function.
Here is the key generator script:
#!/bin/bash

if echo $* | grep -e "-p" -q
then
   src_file="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")/$2"
else
   src_file="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")/../keys/paths.yaml"
fi

keys=$(echo $(wc -l $src_file) | head -c 1);

parse_yaml() {
   local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s[:-]$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" "$1" |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;
      for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
      if (length($3) > 0) {
         vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
         printf("%s%s%s=(\"%s\")\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
      }
   }'
}

eval $(parse_yaml $src_file)

# Check if private_key variable is set
if [ -z "$private_key" ]; then
  echo "Error: private_key variable not found in yaml file."
  exit 1
fi

# Generate private key
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048

# Loop through all the public keys
for key in ${!public_key_*}; do
  # Generate public key from the private key
  openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -out "${!key}.pem"
  # Move the public key to its specified directory
  echo "${!key}"
  echo "$BABYLON_APP_DIR/${!key}"
  mv "${!key}.pem" "$BABYLON_APP_DIR/${!key}/public_key.pem"
done

# Move the private key to its specified directory
mv private_key.pem "$BABYLON_APP_DIR/$private_key"

Did anyone encountered something similar? I ran out of ideas...
